# Differentiability question using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Could anyone please help me with where to start with this question? (c)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the situation is fairly simple away from $0$: you can just use ordinary calculus rules to deal with it. The only concern is at $0$. There you can write

$$1-\sqrt{1-x^2}=\frac{x^2}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

by multiplying top and bottom by the conjugate and simplifying. The point is that this is between $0$ and $x^2$ for $0 < x < 1$. This means that for $0<h<1$

$$0 \leq \frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h} \leq h.$$

Look at $h<0$ yourself. You will find that you get another squeeze theorem setup to calculate $g'(0)$. Now that you have $g'(0)$, you have $g'(x)$ on all of $(-1,1)$. Now do the same kind of thing with that function.

Comment: Where do you get $\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h} \leq h.$ from please?

Comment: @anon For $0<h<1$, $g(h)=\frac{h^2}{1+\sqrt{1-h^2}}$. (You should prove this yourself.) The denominator is at least $1$ for $0 < h < 1$, so $g(h) \leq h^2$. Now $g(0)=0$, so $\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h} \leq h$ for $0<h<1$.

Comment: @anon That expression describes function values for positive $x$ near zero. Function values near zero matter for continuity and differentiability at zero.

Comment: Okay thanks, so we are using this definition yes? Lim (h->0)$ \frac{f(x0 +h)- f(x0)}{h}$ exists implies differentiable?

Comment: @anon Yes. You just need to be careful because when $x_0=0$, the substitution you want to do depends on whether $h>0$ or $h<0$.

Comment: Hmm okay, I shall have a think- thank you

Comment: so do we get limit of -h for one, and h for the other, both of which would be equal to 0?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24001/discussion-between-anon-and-ian).

Comment: Well...you would usually write $\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^-} 0 = 0$. Then $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}$ is where you need the squeeze theorem. You get zero, so the full limit is zero. But you have the idea.

Comment: do we also not need the squeeze theorem for the limit from the left? as we'd have $ -h \leq \frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h} \leq 0$ ?

Comment: @anon In the limit from the left the quotient is just zero, because $g(h)=0$ for $-1<h<0$.

Comment: One final question, how do we know what to take the interval for h to be? Is it just our interval for x? Thanks a lot for your help- it is much appreciated

Comment: @anon Yeah, it's where you know which expression to use for $g$, basically.