# Real Analysis Question- Differentiability on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

[image: Question]

So this is the question I am trying to answer... At $(-2,0)$ and $(0,2)$ we just differentiate using normal rules of calculus, yes? Here is my attempt for at $x=0$.[image] Is this correct?

For d)I think I can show it is continuous by limit as x tends to 0 from the left (limit of $\frac{-x}{(4-x^2)}= 0$ and likewise from the right. However, I'm unsure as to why $g'$ is not differentiable at $0$, is it again necessary to use the definition of the derivative? However, in the first part of the question I said '$2$' is differentiable and the derivative is $0$. Can I not apply this logic to this question?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you compute the derivative of $g'$ for $x \in (-2,0]$ then you'll find that $g''(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$. But then if you take any $x \in (0, 2)$ and take the limit from the right,
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}g''(x)=0$$
since $g''(x)=0 \enspace \forall x \in (0,2)$. But $0 \neq -\frac{1}{2}$ which means the limit does not exist and thus $g'$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you think what I have done in the photo is correct for the first part? Thanks

Comment: Yes, except for the right limit of $g'(x)$ you must use the definition of $g$ for $x \in (0, 2)$

Comment: So would I just say the derivative of 2 is 0 so the right limit is 0? Bit confused

Comment: Yep that's perfect.

Comment: Great- thanks very much!

Comment: And I still say limit as h tends to 0+ ? (=0)

Comment: You do indeed! :-)

Comment: I am just a bit confused because if you see my previous question I asked about the subject I was told not to do this

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293025/differentiability-question-using-the-definition/1293052#1293052

Comment: Actually- ignore this- haha!